# Where can I find an online scheduler to organize a trip?

Tags: google-calendar

I need to organize a trip with friends, and this is the opportunity to check free online schedulers. Is [Google Calendar](http://www.google.com/calendar/render) the right tool for this, or are there better alternatives?

Ideally, it should include both a calendar and some simple to-do tool so as to assign tasks to the troops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you and your friends all have Google accounts, Google Calendar is a great tool.  Another nice feature of Google Calendar is that you can access it from your phone.

Comment: and google calendar do have a simple To Do feature, I believe you can add it through labs.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Google Calendar + its Tasks add-on is just right for what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need, [TripIt](http://tripit.com) may do what you want.  It is centered around travel for an individual, but will let you share information with selected people.  The great thing about it is that, after you register your email addresses, you simply forward confirmation emails from airlines, hotels, etc to plans@tripit.com.  It parses them and builds an itinerary for you automatically.  It seems to be pretty accurate when I've used it.

Comment: TripIt has an iPhone app.  If they don't already have a Blackberry app, they're working on it.

Answer (score 0):

**OnTheRoad**

- http://www.ontheroad.to/
- maybe this tool is right for you
- [list of features](http://www.ontheroad.to/features)

Answer (score 0):

I've used [BaseCamp](http://basecamphq.com/) for something similar in the past. It's centred more around project management than planning a trip but it worked well